# how to make footer stay at the end of scroll

Tags: css

I have html

```
    <head>

    </head>

     <body>

     </body>

     <footer>

      </footer>
```

now what I want is the footer stay at the very end of the page and the user should scroll to see it.
would you help me please?

I tried :

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom:-100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

but setting height:100px and bottom:-100px get it hidden while I want the user to be able to scroll down to see it

Answer (score 0):

add style `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` to your footer

Comment: I tried this but when I set height:100px; bottom:-100px; it get hidden while I want the user to be able to scroll down to see it